# Phrase or idiom for "vocal minority"

Tags: translation, mandarin

How do you say "vocal minority" in Chinese? Specifially, in Mandarin?

Answer (score 1):

1. The translation for 'minority' is straightforward: `少數派`. Note: not `小數派` (`少` refers to little in quantity, `小` refers to little in (physical) size). To be concise, you may say `少數`.
2. For 'vocal', `敢言的` or `直言不諱的` (see [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/zhs/%E8%AF%8D%E5%85%B8/%E8%8B%B1%E8%AF%AD-%E6%B1%89%E8%AF%AD-%E7%B9%81%E4%BD%93/vocal)) are translations that give it a fairly positive light. Tang Ho's answer `積極的` is neutral, somewhat positive.
3. `發聲的` is a literal translation but understandable (I for one think it is understandable, given that you're not translating the term alone but with a wider context). A neutral alternative, albeit slightly weak, is to say `不沈默的少數` which makes deliberate reference to its antonym 'silent majority' (`沈默的大多數`). I also found a third neutral translation, `說話大聲的少數族群`, in a book on journalism published in Taiwan<sup>1</sup>, where vocal minority is contrasted to the disadvantaged minority. **Finally, I find the neutral translation `喊叫的少數` made by the Taiwanese politician James Soong in one of his works<sup>2</sup> the most idiomatic of them all.**
4. If you want to be outright negative (considering the fact that vocal minority can be euphemistic), you may consider the idiomatic saying `一小撮人的意見` (lit. the opinion of a handful of people), but this is not a direct translation and is quite dismissive. **A Japanese political publication<sup>3</sup> gave the translation `うるさい少数派` (a possible Chinese translation: `嘈吵的少數` 'noisy minority') which I think is best in delivering the negative nuance.**

<sup>1</sup> `何日生（2007）《建構式新聞》。台灣：五南，頁175。`

<sup>2</sup> `宋楚瑜（1978）《美國政治與民意：兼論中美關係》。台灣：黎明文化，頁51。`

<sup>3</sup> `信田智人（1996）『官邸の権力』筑摩書房 pp. 230`

Answer (score 0):

The literal translation of vocal minority is '有聲音的少數民族/ 有聲音的小數派'

- 'Minority' in  'vocal minority' doesn't mean '少數民族'. It means '少數派' as in '少數派意見' (minority opinion)
- 'Vocal' here doesn't simply mean '有聲音的' (that have a voice) or 發出聲音的 (that makes sound). The deeper implication is 'being active' (in express opinions/ voicing demands or objections)

Translate 'vocal minority' as '積極少數派' (active minority) would express the meaning of the term more clearly in Chinese

Answer (score 0):

I like: 人数不多但敢于直言 = a vocal minority

抗议者人数不多但敢于直言。
The protesters are a small but vocal minority.

Found another interesting translation:

他们人数不多但在反对时他们嗓门很大！

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to say "vocal minority" in Chinese, largely depends on the type of group/event one wants to describe/depict.

- 呱噪少數
- 激進少數
- 活躍少數
- 積極少數
- 不干沉默的少數